# How to write a tree class where nodes can be accessed by position?

Tags: python, algorithm, class, data-structures, tree

I aim to write a class representing a general tree where nodes can be accessed by giving positions given that new nodes can be added as child to existing and so on.Also positional access has to be written in O(1) time. So far I have decided to write a node and a tree class. Node class for starters is as follows:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.children=[]
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
    def add_child(self,n,pos=-1)#pos describes position of new child
        if not pos:
            pos=len(self.children)
        if not type(n)==type(node()):
            n=node(n)
        self.children.insert(n)
```

Positional access means that in following tree:

```
                  1
             2         3
           4   5         6
```

position 1 has value 1, position 2 has value 2 and so on?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is really a computer science question, not a Python question really. Do you have a textbook you can refer to?

Comment: This is sort of exercise in the book. Data Structure and algorithms in Java. I've only used python to represent my class. Answer in pseudocode or any language is acceptable

Comment: if this isn't for an assignment you can just use a dictionary, there are also python libraries out there that can do node trees: https://pythonspot.com/python-tree/

Comment: What you're describing is simply visiting the nodes of the tree (aka [tree-traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) it) in what is called "top-down" or "breadth-first" order.

Comment: Yes I get that but still can you bfs will not solve in O(1) time

Comment: What you are describing sounds confusing and impossible.  But lots of things that sound similar to it are quite doable.  Can you please give the problem **exactly** as stated to clarify?

Comment: Write a class  for a general tree where nodes can be accessed by their positions.

Comment: how do you access nodes by their position. Tree is not a list

Comment: Could you please update the question and quote literally what the assignment is (if it is one), including all definitions and constraints? Any constraints on time compexity for insert, delete?